# Kivy - Fetching and displaying data

Tags: python, kivy

**Background**
I have fetched some data from a server using `UrlRequest` which looks like this(response)

```
{"class":["neg",0,1,0,0,0,1]}
```

and I want to display the above list and the elements on a Label. To do that I created a `classification = ListProperty([])` inside my Widget class in which I stored the response by doing

```
def got_json(self, req,result):
        self.classification =  result['class']
```

.
**The Problem**
When I do this to display the above list everything looks fine and the Output looks like the img

```
Label:
      text: str(root.classification)
```

[image]

Furthur when I do this to make sure about the length of List, it looks fine too and the output looks like

```
Label:
      text: str(len(root.classification))
```

[image]

*However* when I try to access individual elements of the list

```
Label:
      text: root.classification[0]
```

It throws out an

> IndexError: list index out of range

.I also tried converting it into a list and doing

```
Label:
      text: list(root.classification)[0]
```

But it threw the same error. So it shows the length of 7 and when I access the first element, it throws an out of range error?

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for me. Just make sure this is really your classification list

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the response. Could it be that at  time of receiving the data I have to convert it? I was stuck at the time of requesting in the past, turned out I had to json.dump the data at the time of sending a request. I should take a look at it again.

Comment: @SPSP Still seeing the same error. How could it be that the length of `classification` is 7 but accessing the first or last index gives `Index out of range` ?

Comment: @SPSP Turns out the error was way more interesting than I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kovak on the Kivy IRC channel, doing

```
Label:
      text: root.classification[0]  if len(root.classification) > 0 else 'empty list'
```

fixed it. Turns out that when I declared `classification = ListProperty([])` its also evaluating for that initial `[]` empty list till the data is received from server, however short that is, and hence indexing `AnyList[0]` when `AnyList` is empty would probably throw an `Index Out of Range` error. Although `len` works fine, that's because of how Properties work in Kivy